# android websocket websocketnotconnected error

Tags: java, android, em-websocket-client

I have used Java-WebSocket (https://github.com/Davidiusdadi/Java-WebSocket) Client in my android app.

I am recording an audio file and sending it to server using websocketclient and Draft 17.

my audio file is of 500 kb = 500000 bytes. i am splitting the same into 1000 bytes string.

So I have 500 string. which i send as a Json to server in a loop in an async task.

After sending few messages while i call websocketclient.send i am getting an exception saying websocketnotconnected and no onclose or onerror is triggered yet.

Some times it works properly.

Is there any solution to this or any other android websocket library that is suitable for above task.

Comment: Posting the relevant parts of your code would help a lot.

Comment: Why don't you try a new WebSocket client library, nv-websocket-client?

https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client